# What's the programming language of this code snippet?

Tags: code-snippets

```
procedure F0110

clear screen

clear gets

if (SubStr(dir_fin, 1, 9) == "C:\Folder1")

     set color to /W

endif
```

What language is it ?

Comment: Looks like [Clipper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipper_%28programming_language%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clipper http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipper_programming_language

CLEAR SCREEN: http://vivaclipper.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/c5_clear-screen/

CLEAR GETS: http://vivaclipper.wordpress.com/2014/02/15/clear-gets/

Comment: Thanks, it really is clipper!

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be dBase, based on the "set color to /W" line.